# How to render HTML from Json webtemplate

Tags: json, angular, openehr

I have my own json webtemplate where it contains nested elements. I want to render HTML according to the json contained in webtemplate.

I used ngx-schema-form, but I don't have properties variable inside my json. And also used formly but I couldn't achieve with that as well.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How is this related to openehr?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using "ngx-schema-form", you will have to modify your json w.r.t the needs of the library, the "properties" will be used by the library to dynamically create a form control.

Comment: Which angular library is compatible to render forms from my  json template?